# Need to toggle vibrator option on or off

Tags: java, android

I am currently building my first android application using android studio. I have a button pressing game and currently it vibrates when pressing a button during the game. I want to make a toggle to turn the button on and off. Currently, I have something like this:

```
public void onCheckBoxClicked(View view){
    Vibrator vibrate = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox)R.id.vibratecbx).isChecked();

    if(checked){
    }
    else{
        vibrate.cancel();
    }
}
```

I am receiving an error with regards to the line ((CheckBox)R.id.vibratecbx) with regards to incompatible types, so i'll need a fix on that, as well as to see how I can toggle the actual vibration option on or off for the game.
Thank you :)

Here is the main game file section where the button is then being pressed:

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //vibrate on press
            Vibrator vibrate = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            boolean isVibrator = vibrate.hasVibrator();
            if(isVibrator)
                vibrate.vibrate(50);
```

Answer (score 1):

((CheckBox)R.id.vibratecbx) doesn't give you a CheckBox.

If you want to use your CheckBox you need to get a reference to it from the xml you inflated.

For example in your Activity you could get your Checkbox during the onCreate

```
private CheckBox myCheckBox;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.vibratecbx);
    }
```

And then you can use myCheckBox as you wish.

**EDIT**

You can save the state of the CheckBox and use it when you click on a button.
So that in your onClickListener you can check whether or not the app should vibrate.

As such :

```
    private CheckBox myCheckBox;
    private Vibrator myVibrator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.vibratecbx);

        myVibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        ....
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // ... your actions
                if(myVibrator.hasVibrator() && myCheckBox.isChecked())
                {
                    // Vibrate for 400 milliseconds
                    myVibrator.vibrate(400);
                }
            }
        });
       }
```

Comment: Brilliant! No errors :) But the original intent of this question was to see how i can use the if / else statement to switch vibrate on or off for the application. Any idea how?

Comment: Although this might look good, I have another instance of vibrator being initialised in the game class since it would need it to vibrate when the button of the button clicker game is pressed. I edited my question to include the other section of the code

Comment: I edited my suggestion, you can have your Vibrator be a class field so that you instantiate it only one time and use it again in the OnClickListener